# Phone/Skype call from website using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phone-number

I have a list phone number. when i click a button, if count of list = 1 then call from phone or skype, if count of list > 1 then open modal with list phone number.
Please help me.

Comment: please show us what you've tried already, some code snippets and more. :)